# What does it mean that most dropped packets have a different incoming and outgoing port?

Tags: router, tcp, port, udp, analysis

Over the weekend an internet-facing DI-624 router of mine was e-mailing me logs like crazy for some reason.  Normally it's a few a day, but it was about one every few minutes instead.  Analyzing the messages, I found that only 340 had the same src and dst port number, whereas the majority of "default deny" dropped packets (28,000+) had the two ports different.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source ports and destination ports are normally going to be different.  This is normal.  When you connect to web site as a client to destination port 80, the OS will likely give the packet a high number source port that is maybe random.  Go read about [Ephemeral Ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). This aids in the OS keeping track of which session is which.

Comment: Thanks!  So I guess it's only worth looking at the destination ports, then, if anything.